# How can I re-render MUI data table upon any user action in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui, react-hooks

I have one Lock-Unlock button and a delete button, So the problem is when I render data from axios using useEffect hook its working, but if I lock or unlock a user the table is not changing automatically. That means axios is not getting called.

In that case if I put the useState hook in the useEffect, API is getting called multiple times, that is not as expected. In that case can anyone suggest me how can I re render data table as soon as user clicks on lock-unlock button.

FYI, lock unlock functionality is working 100% correctly. What is needed I have to go to other page and again come back to my datatable page in order to see the change.

code snippet:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
}));
/*
    Customization of mui
 */
const getMuiTheme = () => createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFE"
      }
    }
  }
});

/* eslint-disable */
const UserDetailsDatatable = () => {
  // console.log('POS: ' + localStorageService.getItem("auth_user"));

  if(localStorageService.getItem("auth_user") == null){
    history.push({
      pathname: "/session/signin"
    });
  }
    
    const [responsive, setResponsive] = useState("vertical");
    const [dataRenderHook, setDataRenderHook] = useState([]);
    const [tableBodyHeight, setTableBodyHeight] = useState("650px");
    const [tableBodyMaxHeight, setTableBodyMaxHeight] = useState("");
    
    const classes = useStyles();

    // Redirect to edit
    const newMountpage = (rowData) => {
      var pickedUpRowData = rowData.rowData;
      let path = `/Admin/users/editUser`; 
      history.push({
        pathname: path,
        state: {detail: pickedUpRowData} 
      });
    };

    /* Deletion */
    const deleteRow = (rowDatam) => {
      deleteUser(rowDatam);
      
    };
    /* User Locker/Unlocker */
    const LockerUnlocker = (Iopticore_ID, state) => {
      console.log('State: '+ state);
      lockerUnlocker(Iopticore_ID, Boolean(state));
    }

    const ChangeHandler = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    };
  
    const columns = [
    {
      name: "userID",
      label: "Iopticore_ID",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      }
      },
    {
      name: "userName",
      label: "Corporate ID",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "name",
      label: "User Name",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "email",
      label: "Email",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "role",
      label: "Role",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "external",
      label: "IsExternal",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        filterOptions: {
          names: ["Yes", "No"],
          logic(v, filterVal) {
            const show =
              (filterVal.indexOf("Yes") >= 0 && ( v === true || v === 'true') ) ||
              (filterVal.indexOf("No") >= 0 && ( v === false || v === 'false') );
            return !show;
          }
        },
        customBodyRender: (val) => {
          return val === true ? "Yes" : "No";
        }
      }
     },
    {
      name: "locked",
      label: "Access",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        empty: true,
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        filterOptions: {
          names: ["Yes", "No"],
          logic(v, filterVal) {
            const show =
              (filterVal.indexOf("Yes") >= 0 && ( v === true || v === 'true') ) ||
              (filterVal.indexOf("No") >= 0 && ( v === false || v === 'false') );
            return !show;
          }
        },
        customBodyRender: (val, tableMeta) => {
          //console.log('v: ' + val + ' ' + JSON.stringify(tableMeta))  ;
          return val === true ? (
            <Fab 
              size="small" 
              variant="extended" 
              aria-label="Delete"
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              onClick={() => LockerUnlocker(tableMeta.rowData[0], tableMeta.rowData[6])}
              >
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/25/000000/unlock.png"/>
              &nbsp;<b>UnLock&nbsp;</b>
            </Fab>
          ) : (
            <Fab 
              size="small" 
              variant="extended" 
              aria-label="Delete"
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              onClick={() => LockerUnlocker(tableMeta.rowData[0])}
              >
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/25/000000/unlock.png"/>
              <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lock&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    },
     {
      name: "Edit",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <Fab 
            size="small" 
            color="primary" 
            aria-label="Edit" 
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => newMountpage(tableMeta)}
            >
              <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: "Delete",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        textAlign: 'center',
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <Fab size="small" 
            color="secondary" 
            aria-label="Edit" 
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => deleteRow(tableMeta.rowData[0])}
            >
              <Icon>delete_icon</Icon>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    }];
  
    const options = {
      selectableRows: 'none',
      filter: true,
      textAlign: 'center',
      filterType: "dropdown",
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      pagination: true,
      responsive,
      enableNestedDataAccess: '.',
      tableBodyHeight,
      tableBodyMaxHeight
    };
    
    var recentReceivedToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtAuthtokenManager');
    
    
    var res= [];
      useEffect(() => { 
        
        (async () => {
          res = await axios.get('<URL>', {
            headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer  ${recentReceivedToken}`}
          }, 
          // console.log('Hola : ' + JSON.stringify(res))
      )
      .catch((error)=> {
        if(error.response.status != 200){
          swal({
            title: "Opps! Access Denied",
            imageUrl: 'https://notionpress.com/new-rewamp/images/404-error.gif',
            text: "You Might Not Have Access To This Page.",
            icon: "error",
          });
        } 
      })
      //console.log('Res : ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      setDataRenderHook(res.data);
      
      })();        
      }, []);
      
    //console.log('Data Promise : ' + renderDatatable());
    if(dataRenderHook.length === 0){
      //console.log('Length: 0');
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{padding:40}}>
          
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
          <LinearBuffer />
          </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          
          </div>    
          
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }else{
      //console.log('Length: 1');    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{padding:40}}>
          
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <MUIDataTable
            title={"IoptiCore User List"}
            data={dataRenderHook}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
          />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          
          </div>    
          
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    
}

export default UserDetailsDatatable;
```

Comment: what does the lock/unlock do? more specifically, what does/should it change about the UI?

Comment: @ZekeHernandez Lock-Unlock is a button that locks an user and unlock opens an user. Simply Lock has an icon with LOCK and unlock has an icon of Unlock. I just want to toggle between this two switches, as soon as the action is performed. You can see it here, ***name: "locked",*** attribute under column const.

Comment: so it calls the `lockerUnlocker` function. From your code sample, it's not clear what that function does. But I'm guessing it changes something in the db, yeah? So it sounds like you *need* to have the API called every time you lock/unlock, right?

Comment: Yup you're right @ZekeHernandez. it called an api and marks a field true or false. so I have to call axios every time the action is performed.

Comment: so when you mark something as locked, after a successful update to the db, you can just  call another fetch and call `setDataRenderHook` again yeah?

Comment: @ZekeHernandez its throwing TypeError: t.map is not a function

Comment: which would indicate that t is not an array and it should be. But that's all I can gather from that error message, you'd have to look at the stack trace to see where that's happening and why.

Comment: I solved it. By using a simple hook while putting the axios call in separate async function. when I user performs an action, I called the async func. that returns a promise. Then I assigned the promise into setState, and simply passed the useState hook inside useEffect. thats all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { makeStyles,createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Icon,  Fab } from "@material-ui/core";
import history from "history.js";
import axios from "axios";
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import LinearBuffer from './EditUserHelper/progresscircle';
import lockerUnlocker from './Lock_Unlock/lockerUnlocker';
import deleteUser from './DeleteUser/DeleteUser'
import localStorageService from "../../../services/localStorageService";
import apiDataReturner from "./userAxios";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
}));
/*
    Customization of mui
 */
const getMuiTheme = () => createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFE"
      }
    }
  }
});

/* eslint-disable */
const UserDetailsDatatable = () => {
  // console.log('POS: ' + localStorageService.getItem("auth_user"));

  if(localStorageService.getItem("auth_user") == null){
    history.push({
      pathname: "/session/signin"
    });
  }
    
    const [responsive, setResponsive] = useState("vertical");
    const [dataRenderHook, setDataRenderHook] = useState([]);
    const [tableBodyHeight, setTableBodyHeight] = useState("650px");
    const [tableBodyMaxHeight, setTableBodyMaxHeight] = useState("");
    const [tracker, setTracker] = useState();
    
    const classes = useStyles();

    // Redirect to edit
    const newMountpage = (rowData) => {
      var pickedUpRowData = rowData.rowData;
      let path = `/Admin/users/editUser`; 
      history.push({
        pathname: path,
        state: {detail: pickedUpRowData} 
      });
    };

    /* Deletion */
    const deleteRow = (rowDatam) => {
      deleteUser(rowDatam);
      var x = apiDataReturner();
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout(() => {  
          setTracker(x);
        }, 3000); 
      }); 
        
      promise.then(values => { 
        setDataRenderHook(values); 
      }); 
    };
    /* User Locker/Unlocker */
    const LockerUnlocker = (Iopticore_ID, state) => {
      lockerUnlocker(Iopticore_ID, Boolean(state)); 
      var x = apiDataReturner();
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout(() => {  
          setTracker(x);
        }, 3000); 
      }); 
        
      promise.then(values => { 
        setDataRenderHook(values); 
      }); 
      
    }

    const ChangeHandler = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    };
  
    const columns = [
    {
      name: "userID",
      label: "Iopticore_ID",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
        display: false
      }
    },
    {
      name: "userName",
      label: "Corporate ID",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "name",
      label: "User Name",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "email",
      label: "Email",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "role",
      label: "Role",
      options: {
       filter: true,
       responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
       sort: true,
      }
     },
     {
      name: "external",
      label: "IsExternal",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
        filterOptions: {
          names: ["Yes", "No"],
          logic(v, filterVal) {
            const show =
              (filterVal.indexOf("Yes") >= 0 && ( v === true || v === 'true') ) ||
              (filterVal.indexOf("No") >= 0 && ( v === false || v === 'false') );
            return !show;
          }
        },
        customBodyRender: (val) => {
          return val === true ? "Yes" : "No";
        }
      }
     },
    {
      name: "locked",
      label: "Access",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        empty: true,
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
        filterOptions: {
          names: ["Yes", "No"],
          logic(v, filterVal) {
            const show =
              (filterVal.indexOf("Yes") >= 0 && ( v === true || v === 'true') ) ||
              (filterVal.indexOf("No") >= 0 && ( v === false || v === 'false') );
            return !show;
          }
        },
        customBodyRender: (val, tableMeta) => {
          //console.log('v: ' + val + ' ' + JSON.stringify(tableMeta))  ;
          return val === true ? (
            <Fab 
              size="small" 
              variant="extended" 
              aria-label="Delete"
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              onClick={() => LockerUnlocker(tableMeta.rowData[0], tableMeta.rowData[6])}
              >
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/25/000000/unlock.png"/>
              &nbsp;<b>UnLock&nbsp;</b>
            </Fab>
          ) : (
            <Fab 
              size="small" 
              variant="extended" 
              aria-label="Delete"
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              onClick={() => LockerUnlocker(tableMeta.rowData[0])}
              >
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/25/000000/unlock.png"/>
              <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lock&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    },
     {
      name: "Edit",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        responsive: 'scrollFullHeightFullWidth',
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <Fab 
            size="small" 
            color="primary" 
            aria-label="Edit" 
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => newMountpage(tableMeta)}
            >
              <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: "Delete",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        textAlign: 'center',
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        responsive: 'scrollMaxWidth',
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <Fab size="small" 
            color="secondary" 
            aria-label="Edit" 
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => deleteRow(tableMeta.rowData[0])}
            >
              <Icon>delete_icon</Icon>
            </Fab>
          );
        }
      }
    }];
  
    const options = {
      selectableRows: 'none',
      filter: true,
      textAlign: 'center',
      filterType: "dropdown",
      fixedHeaderOptions:true,
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      pagination: true,
      responsive: 'stacked',
      enableNestedDataAccess: '.',
      tableBodyHeight,
      tableBodyMaxHeight
    };
    
    //var recentReceivedToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtAuthtokenManager');
    
    
    var res= [];
      useEffect(() => { 
        var x = apiDataReturner();
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
          setTimeout(() => { 
              resolve(x); 
          }, 2000); 
        }); 
          
        promise.then(values => { 
          setDataRenderHook(values); 
        });        
      }, [tracker]);      
    
    if(dataRenderHook.length === 0){
      return(
        
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{padding:0}}>
          
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
          <LinearBuffer />
          </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          
          </div>    
          
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }else{   
      return (
        <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div style={{padding:0}}>
          
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <MUIDataTable
            title={"IoptiCore User List"}
            data={dataRenderHook}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
          />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          
          </div>    
          
        </React.Fragment>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
}

export default UserDetailsDatatable;
```

Sharing the code, it might help someone.